# How to dereference an Objective-C object via its pointer/memory address?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management, runtime, nsobject

So, it is very easy to get an object pointer's "memory address", á la..

`id x = @"obj"; printf("'x' is at: %p", x);`

> `'x' is at: 0x100b60048`

Amazingly, I cannot seem to find ANY reference as to how to perform the "reverse" operation. ie. get a reference to an object pointer, either via the hex `int` pointer address, or it's string representation ...

```
NSString  * ptr = @"0x100b60048";
unsigned   addr = 0;
NSScanner * scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:ptr];
[scn scanHexInt:&addr];
```

I did come across the following "way", but it a) *doesn't work* (it crashes) and b) irks the fragile sensibilities of the compiler (aka, it emits warnings, lol).

```
id z = (__bridge id)((void*)addr);
```

So, what is "right", modern, ARC-compatible way to do this?

Comment: I guess the only right way would be: don't do it. But may I ask what you need it for?

Comment: I want to be able to pass a reference to an object as a string.

Comment: this sounds extremely dangerous. why would you do that?

Comment: I *do hope* that my down-voters have real issue with the form/validity/content of my question - and aren't just reprimanding my curiosity with the sanctimonious, best-practices-only-party-line. 

Comment: I do have a real issue with the content: you still didn't explain, why you would pass strings instead of the pointer/object itself. If you could show us a real need I'd say your architecture is broken and should be fixed instead.

Comment: There are so many reasons one may want to do this, it would impossible to list them all. Off the top of my head.. 1: the object does't exist yet, or  2: The receiver of the string (to decode) is in a different room, city, universe, etc. 3. The receiver only knows how to read strings, etc. Innovation occurs _despite_, not _because of_ standard practices, y'all.

Comment: How do u know the address of a not existing object? you call it innovation, I call it raping of OOP.

Comment: If the object doesn't exist yet, how do you know its address??  (I suspect you have some serious misconceptions.)

Comment: Given the things that you _do_ want to do with this, my real question is why not perform serialization/deserialization of the object where you need it? Why not convert your object to some standard format, pass that along however you wish, and decode on the other side?

Comment: *different room, city, universe, etc*. Did u managed to create a distributed OS where all devices share the same memory space? Otherwise an address on one device won't have any meaning  on another.

Comment: *The receiver only knows how to read strings, etc*. a cpu only knows bytes or words. string already is an interpretation of them.

Comment: Not sure why all y'all's tail feathers are so rustled over the suggestion.  I mean this has been done *a million times before* - it's the basis of `NSArchiving` and `DistributedObjects`, among countlesss other serialization techniques. ALL of the `ObjC` runtime is based on passing messages around.. is it really so outrageous that someone might think to use this readily available, direct representation of an object for more than printing it to a log!?

Comment: @alexgray No, representing an object by using the address as a string **and then converting that string back to a reference** is not how archiving, DO, or the ObjC runtime works.  The moment you talk about different app sessions, different machines or even different documents in a single application, the conversion from string to reference will fail.

Comment: @alexgray To be clear, we're not trying to shoot you down because we think that you're wrong for not using best practices; we're trying to get a clear image of what you're trying to do so we can help clear up any misconceptions you might have, and give you better tools for doing what you're looking to do. You _CANNOT_ simply send memory references around between processes, across sessions, etc., because it doesn't work (you're not sharing the same memory space). Instead, we're trying to suggest things you can do to avoid sending references around.

Comment: @alexgray The technologies you mentioned don't work like this, because they _can't_ work like this. So instead, we're trying to suggest things that _do_ work, and happen to be best practices _because_ they work; I'm not suggesting object serialization because it's a best practice — I'm suggesting it because it's the exact solution to the problem you're trying to solve (passing objects around in a non-fragile way). If this isn't solving your problem, then you'll have to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 2):

> So, what is "right", modern, ARC-compatible way to do this?

The right way?   Don't do it.

For an object to remain in memory in an ARC'd application, there needs to be a strong reference to said object (or you have to do something really nasty with the CF APIs).   And any pointer-in-a-string will only be valid during the lifetime of the app;  quit and restart?  All addresses are now bogus.

So, if you really want to refer to a random object in a string, then do this:

- stick the object in a dictionary with an NSNumber or an NSString as a key (you can even use the address of the object as the value but I would recommend against it because addresses don't survive app re-launches and you'll probably someday want to persist that dictionary)
- when you parse the string, extract the key and look up the object

That way, you'll never have to cast between int and ptr, you won't have to use a ton of dangerous typecasting to quiet the compiler and your code will be ARC compatible.

Comment: I agree and concur with you on all of your points.  The theoretical task I had imagined, though.. involved "parties" that wouldn't both have access to such a  "shared" container as to hold the actual object.

Comment: @alexgray Then all parties need to have some notion of a common key to access the actual object.   And if the parties exist on different machines, different app sessions or, even, across closing and opening a document, then a string representation of an address *will not work*.

Answer (score 1):

So this works. That being said, I would be very uncomfortable relying on this in a project of mine. If that variable gets released before you scan its address, who knows what you're going to get. In that respect, I guess that breaks the "ARC compatible" criterion because who knows when that reference will get released which makes this very dangerous. Also, type safety is totally out the window.

```
NSString *pointer = @"test";
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p",pointer];

NSString *retrievedObject;
sscanf([address cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%p", &retrievedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, well I did figure out a relatively painless way to do this, so I'll post it here for hazing / nitpicking and even, < gasp > ... *possible acceptance* ... Using the original question's variables...

```
/// this requires a "0x" formatted hex string                                              
ptr = [ptr hasPrefix:@"0x"] ? ptr :
      [@"0x" stringByAppendingString:ptr];

uintptr_t hex = strtoull(ptr.UTF8String, NULL, 0);
    id gotcha = (__bridge id)(void *)hex;
```